# The page not found page lacks alt text

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error, accessibility

> We couldn't find the page you requested. We did find this sign which might help.

The image next to it doesn't have alt text associated with it.

If you don't know anything about the image, you might think the second sentence of the quote wasn't sarcastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd have to customize this per site which is more work than it's worth.

But I did change it to

`alt="page not found"`

which is at least not blank as it was before.